# OutOfMemoryException - Strategies to overcome this problem?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, out-of-memory

First of all, I am aware that this question has been discussed many times in this forum, such as 
[Large array C# OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791868/large-array-c-outofmemoryexception) and
[OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590840/outofmemoryexception)

The object I am having problem with is

```
Dictionary<long, Double> results
```

which stores ID in long and calculation result in Double

I will have to reuse the same object about 10~20 times, every time when I reuse it I will call a

```
results = new Dictionary<long, Double>
```

I know that I can write it to a text file or database file for further processing but if possible I would try to avoid that as it is way too slow for the amount of data I handling. I have also tried GC.Collect() but no luck with that.

Can anyone with some previous experience give some pointer on this?

Edit: I have > 3 million objects in the list, but they are fixed (i.e. the key is the same in all iterations)

Comment: Can you clear it instead of creating a new one every time? Memory allocation can be expensive.

Comment: Do you really have to use a long for the ID? How many items are in your dictionary?

Comment: @Chibacity: 3 million items I have

Comment: @cherhan You don't need long IDs then. Use int IDs instead as this will have a range of up to ~2 billion, and will only use 4 bytes vs 8 bytes per item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating 20 different instances, use one, but clear the list (which allows the GC to collect old elements) so that you have more memory to work with. Also, moving to a 64 bit environment might be wise if you require huge amounts of memory.

Comment: Not an answer - this makes no sense given the volumes involved. Unless the OP is totally off with his description this could never the be problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ah - no. Makes also little sense to get out of memory exceptions in your calls.

I STRONGLY suggest you get serious in analysing - put a memory profiler onto the program and find the real problem. a long/double combo makes zero sense unless you store some hundred million pairs, and even then....

And: A moe to 64 bit is always wise. The 2 / 3 gb limit per process is harder on .net due to GC "overhead" - impossible to use up all the memory. 64 bit has much higher limits.

But again, your indication is wrong. The new Dictionary likely is NOT the error at all, something else wastes your memory.

Comment: A move to 64bit is worth considering if you have sufficient physical memory, otherwise you may be flopping around in the paging file instead. If there is iteration over large data structures and not enough physical memory this can be *very* painful.

Comment: Just FYI I am using VS.NET 2010 on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Still in the debugger you run 32 bit ;) And - @ chibacity - every stupid little computer today can handle 64 bit nicely. The per process limit is 2gb without patches, 3 with in 32 bit. Hardly any computer has not more memory.

Comment: @TomTom You misunderstand me. Whilst 64bit gives you very large virtual address space, this still has to be backed up by physical memory if you don't want to spend most of your time in the paging file.

Comment: Yes, but most copaneis have more than 2gb in their computers. See, it is 2011, not 1980. And the 32 bit limit is LOW.

Comment: @TomTom Gosh - I bow to your superior knowledge of what year it is. Paging files obviously have no relationship to memory management, please forgive me for bringing it up... :(

Comment: They have, but you make it too simplistic and fail to see the real issue here, like memory fragmentation in the 2gb address space which can lead to a lot of unsed space under pressure. People like you fail on memory pressure situations due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: @TomTom "People like me". Wow, you're a gentlemen **and** a scholar.

Comment: No, just someone regualrly firing incompetent develoeprs. The issues under memory prssure for 32 bit are eell documented. It is not virtual memory - it is that the memroy fragments and the GC leaves starts getting problems around 1.2 gigabyte used memory in an application. 64 bit allows this to expand significantly .Even with virtual memory, the fragmented memory is not used, so the overhead is low. In fact, this is one of the areas I regualrly remove possible developes from teams - explain limitations of 32 bit memory and the garbage collector.

Comment: A lot of C# professionals are ignorant in these areas, sadly. That said, I found around 1.2 giga the practical limit - more if you ahve a lot of small ojects, around that when you deal with larger objects.

Comment: @TomTom I know everything you've said, and a lot more. The way you put it forth to me is presumptuous, arrogant with a dash of the bully. I'm sure you're quite a sweet heart really.

Answer (score 1):

if the issue is simply that the memory isn't being freed as expected; perhaps if you use ".Clear()" on the dictionary rather than re-creating every time?