# Abandoned memory in posting image data to server

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, json.net

Showing high consumption of memory while posting image data to server and it is not releasing. `reportModel` in following source code has base64 string of image data. Here is a snapshot of source code,

```
public async Task<FaultReportResponseModel> ReportFault(ReportFaultRequestModel reportModel)
    {
        try
        {
            App.IsConnectedToInternet(true);
            reportModel.Token = App.WebOpsToken;

            //var httpContent = CreateHttpContent(reportModel);

            var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reportModel);
            _log.Trace("ReportFault api jsonBody length: {0}", jsonBody.Length);

            var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            AddAuthorizationHeader();

            string serviceURL;
            if (reportModel.IssueType == IssueTypes.CantFind)
            {
                serviceURL = Constants.CantFindSvcURL;
            }
            else
            {
                serviceURL = Constants.ReportFaultSvcURL;
            }

            //var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", Constants.DataSVCBaseURL, serviceURL);
            var url = GetURLStringForService(serviceURL, ServiceType.WebOpsData);

            var response = await _restClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaultReportResponseModel>(responseStr);
            _log.Trace("Uploaded fault text: {0}", parsedResponse.OK);

            content.Dispose();

            return parsedResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Trace("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Snapshot of the memory footprint,
[image]

It is showing that Json serialization is taking memory and that never got released. Because of this abandoned memory, after few cycles of image upload app crashes.

What I tried,

- Used Stream content to Post to server. In this case, it is showing memory problem in Stream. Problem pointer changed but the problem is same.
- On Internet I found that it is because of Large Object Heap so, I tried to invoke GC manually but no change in memory footprint.

Any help or pointer to get out of this problem would be helpful.

Comment: Please re-read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - images of code are not ok, and you need to make sure sample actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am not assured there is a problem here anyway

Comment: Your string is most likely large enough for it to end up on the LOH. This means it will remain there until a full GC (Gen2) occurs. Taking a single snapshot in time is not enough to see if there's a leak.

Comment: @JohanP as mentioned in question that is candidate of LOH but what is a solution to remove it? or what additional detail you need to help me or point out area that I should look into.

Comment: @Iducool what `HttpClient` are you using?

Comment: @JohanP System.Net.Http.HttpClient with managed implementation.

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035550/large-object-heap-compaction-when-is-it-good is the most appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks but that is just an explanation not how to deal with or solve when you ran into. I have already gone through same post. I already mentioned clue of it in what I tried section.

Comment: `but that is just an explanation not how to deal with` Read it again. Focus specifically on the code sample **in the question** which will compact the LOH, which is likely what you want.

Comment: Your `ReportFaultRequestModel` has the large base64 encoded string. So without doing any IO, your LOH will have that sitting in there. Then you serialize that object, which will create another giant string, going to LOH. Then when you create `StringContent`, that string gets turned into a byte array, another giant allocation going to your LOH.

Comment: I already tried it before asking question here on SO. It is not making any difference in memory footprint.

Comment: Are you able to show that code @Iducool? Just to make sure you implemented it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating large blocks of memory on the LOH. This is likely not a memory heap, though it definitely isn't optimal in high throughput applications

Assuming you want to actually use *Json.Net* on *serialisation* you can achieve this with `JsonTextWriter` and serialize directly to a stream (ideally the `HttpClient` `NetworkStream`). Note that `Test.Json` also has a very efficient methods for serializing to stream as well.

To get access to the underlying `NetworkStream` in `HttpClient`, you could create a derived `HttpContent` class

**Example**

```
public class SerializedStreamedContent<T> :HttpContent
{
   private readonly T _value;
   public SerializedStreamedContent(T value) => _value = value;
   protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext? context)
   {
      try
      {
         using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, leaveOpen:true);
         using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
         var ser = new JsonSerializer();
         ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, _value);
         jsonWriter.Flush();
         return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         return Task.FromException(e);
      }
   }
   protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
   {
      length = -1;
      return false;
   }
}
```

<sub>*Note 1 : This is not intended to be a complete solution, just an example. There are many considerations that you will need to weigh up using this approach*</sub>

<sub>*Note 2 : In *.Net* 5 there is a [JsonContent Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent?view=net-5.0), that does all this for you with `Text.Json` implementation (and more)*</sub>

Comment: As I mentioned in I tried out section of my question, I have tried out stream approach but it changes problem pointer to another place but problem remains same though I will check it out your implmentation and update you.

Comment: @Iducool - then might you please share a [mcve] demonstrating the new problem pointer?  Possibly some other area of your code is creating large buffers.  Related reading: [Efficient api calls with HttpClient and JSON.NET](https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/) and [Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage).